# Can I create new free amazon instance after one year?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I created free amazon ec2 instance with IP X, one year later this instance get expired.

Now after that can I again create new free instance with ip Y?

My uses is very limited and covered up within free limit. What pre caution should be taken while using this free instances?

Answer (score 6):

The AWS Free Tier for Amazon EC2 instances is valid for 12 months after you created your account.  Details are available at http://aws.amazon.com/free/

For EC2, you have 750h/month of t2.micro Linux or Windows instance.  This is equivalent to one instance running 24/7 or 2 instances 12h per day etc ...

If you create a new AWS Account today, you will get another year of free tier with that account

Comment: thanks for your answer. That link I already checked but I am still not clear. Once I created free instance with ip x, i can not create another with different ip, right? i have limited use so not bothering about limit

Comment: The Free Tier is not based on IP addresses.  It is based on the number of hours of t2.micro instance per month.  The Free Tier includes 750h / month of free usage of t2.micro instances.  This is equivalent to one instance running 24h/7 or two instances 12h/day or 10 instances during 75h etc ...